# Expanding * in Ant copy task

Tags: ant

In ant copy task,  in destination location there is a "random number" folder in the path. When i try to put a * in the path to handle it, Ant takes it literally, ie doesnt expand it, but creates a folder called "*" and copies there.  How do I tell Ant to expand the * to actual folder name there (there is only 1 folder in there, so * wont expand to multiple folders)

```
<property name="dest" value="a/*/b/my.jar" />
<property name="src" value="my.jar" />

<copy file="${src}" tofile="${dest}" overwrite="true" verbose="true"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `copy` task doesn't support wildcards in the `tofile` attribute.  If the destination directory exists, but the destination file may not, then you can use a [`dirset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html) to capture the directory.  Something like:

```
<dirset dir="${basedir}" id="dest.dir">
      <include name="a/*/b" />
</dirset>
<property name="dest" value="${toString:dest.dir}/my.jar"/>
<property name="src" value="my.jar" />

<copy file="${src}" tofile="${dest}" overwrite="true" verbose="true"/>
```

Instead of using the property helper (`${toString:....}`) syntax you might use the [`pathconvert` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html):

```
<pathconvert property="destdir" refid="dest.dir"/>
<property name="dest" value="${destdir}/my.jar"/>
```

Comment: Does copy task support wildcards in the "file" attribute?